# Change echo table properties

Tags: php, html-table

I'm having this emergency situation here; my friend has completed my code like this, and I don't know much PHP, here is a table that does not look good!

I can't change the table properties and style, like taking it to the center.

```
function reject(){
global $db_conn;    
$id =  mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);   


$sql = "UPDATE message SET state='deny'
        where id='$id' ";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db_conn) or die(mysql_error());

if($result)
    echo 'deny';
else
    echo 'error';

}
  ############
function show_all(){
global $db_conn;    



echo '<br><br>';
echo  '<table  border="2" > ';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>row</th>';
echo '<th>email</th>';  
echo '<th>place</th>';  
echo '<th>date</th>';   
echo '<th>time</th>';   
echo '<th>situation</th>';      
echo '<th>operation</th>';  


$sql = "select * from message where emailg='$_SESSION[valid_user]'";
$result = mysql_query($sql,$db_conn) or die(mysql_error());
$i=1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    if($i%2==0)
        $class = 'class="even"';
    else
        $class = 'class="odd"';     
    echo '<tr '.$class.'>' ."\n" ;
    echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>'."\n";
    echo '<td>'.$row['emailf'].'</td>'."\n";    
    echo'<td>'.$row['location'].'</td>'."\n";   
    echo'<td>'.$row['date'].'</td>'."\n";
    echo'<td>'.$row['time'].'</td>'."\n";
    echo'<td>'.$row['state'].'</td>'."\n";                                      
    echo '<td><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?op=accept&id='.$row['id'].'">accept</a>|<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?op=reject&id='.$row['id'].'">deny </a>|<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?op=delete&id='.$row['id'].'">delete</a></td>'."\n";          



    echo '</tr>'."\n";

    $i++;   
}



echo '</table>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the visual formatted using css. You only have to modify one thing in the html code. Add a css class to your table :

```
echo  '<table  border="2" class="pic"> ';
```

And customize the rendering with CSS.

Comment: I didi this, but when I want to add the class name , it doesn't recognize the class in my html code

Comment: this is my class:  .pic
{
position: relative;
 left: 60px;
 top: 30px;
 background-color: #2e3e4e
    border: solid 1px #000;
    border-radius: 50%

}

Comment: Ok but I don't see any .pic class inside your table

Comment: I want to add this class to the table, so my table gets these properties